# Three.js Raycaster intersectObjects too slow?

Tags: three.js

I'm writing a Three.js prototype for interacting with objects using the Leap Motion. Each frame (or regularly anyway), I want to check if the representation of the user's finger is above or beneath an object in the scene.

I've done this with the code below, but the intersectObject call is taking about 200 milliseconds, even though it's just testing one object. This is causing the animation to slow down and become very jerky (I've tried doing it e.g. once every 20 frames instead of every frame, but then it still jerks every 20 frames).

Is there a way to do this quicker? Am I doing something wrong? How do other people deal with this?

Thanks!

Code:

```
...

var filepath = '../models/Scissors.js';

loader.load(filepath, function(geometry, materials) {

  scissors = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials) );
  scene.add( scissors );

});

...


function update() {

  ...

  // NB. Sphere1 has been positioned to represent the user's index finger 
  // in 3D space

  var vector = sphere1.position.subSelf( camera.position );

  var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.clone().normalize() );

  var start = new Date().getTime();

  var collisions = ray.intersectObjects( [scissors] );

  // Takes about 200ms
  console.log('Took ' + (new Date().getTime() - start) + ' ms' );

  if( collisions.length > 0 ) {
    console.log('HIT!');
  }

  ...

  requestAnimFrame(update);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, of course the reason it's slow is because the scissors object is a non-trivial model. Now I'm containing it within an invisible cube and testing against that instead. And it's super fast now (0-1 milliseconds) :-)

Comment: could you post a link to a working example or post example code for using an invisible cube? I run into the same problems and I am trying different methods to see which gives me the best overall result.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was for an internal prototype that we can only share within our company. (I can share the video http://labs.pearson.com/prototypes/virtualassist/ but not the actual app). Let me know if I can help you with any specific questions though (peter [dot] oshaughnessy [at] gmail.com if you want to email me).